# JISON issues with parsing command

Tags: javascript, node.js, yacc, lex, jison

Hi I am a newbie to `JISON` and stuck in following code:
For parsing a command:

```
 project -a -n <projectname>
```

My code is as follows:

```
"project"   {return 'PROJECTCOMMAND';}
"-n"        {return 'NAMEOPTION';}
("--add"|"-a")  {return 'ADDOPTION';}  
[-a-zA-Z0-9@\.]+ {return 'TEXT';}

line :   
   PROJECTCOMMAND ADDOPTION NAMEOPTION TEXT 
            {
                //Prject command with project name as argument
                var res = new Object();
                res.value = "addProject name";
                res.name = $4;
                return res;  
            }
```

This works fine if command is as follows:

```
project -a -n samplePro
```

But gives error if command is:

```
project -a -n project
```

Error : Expecting TEXT and got PROJECTCOMMAND.
Same happens if project name in command is project1, project2, myproject, etc.. 
Is there any way I can fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use state. The formal name for what I call "state" here is "start condition" but I find that "state" is a clearer term to me than "start condition".

1. I've declared a new lexer state with `%x TEXT`. There is an `INITIAL` state that exists implicitly. This is the state in which the lexer starts. Any pattern that does not get a state specified exists only in the `INITIAL` state.
2. I've put `<TEXT>` in front of the pattern that results in the `TEXT` token so that this token is generated *only* when we are in the `TEXT` state.
3. I've set the pattern for white space to apply to the states `INITIAL` and `TEXT`.
4. I've made it so that `-n` causes the lexer to enter the `TEXT` state and when a `TEXT` token is encountered, the state is popped.

With this in place, when Jison encounters `-n` in `project -a -n project` it gets into the `TEXT` state where the only things expected are spaces, which are ignored, or `TEXT` tokens. Jison then processes the white space, which it ignores. Then it processes the text that follows which is understood as a `TEXT` token and pops the state.

Complete code:

```
%lex

%x TEXT

%%
"project"   {return 'PROJECTCOMMAND';}
"-n"        {this.begin('TEXT'); return 'NAMEOPTION';}
("--add"|"-a")  {return 'ADDOPTION';}  
<TEXT>[-a-zA-Z0-9@\.]+ {this.popState(); return 'TEXT';}
<INITIAL,TEXT>\s+         // Ignore white space...

/lex

%%

line :   
   PROJECTCOMMAND ADDOPTION NAMEOPTION TEXT 
            {
                //Prject command with project name as argument
                var res = new Object();
                res.value = "addProject name";
                res.name = $4;
                return res;  
            }  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can you please share with me any tutorials where I can learn about these states, begin('TEXT'), popState()